# how to remove table names from column names in beeline query results

Tags: linux, hive, beeline

I am saving beeline query output to a csv file. However the column names in the csv files contain the table name too. For example if table name is `sales` and col name is `Date` then csv has `sales.Date` as the column name. I googled around and found a very good solution in Stack overflow [Hive - How to display Hive query results in the Command Line along with column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896362/hive-how-to-display-hive-query-results-in-the-command-line-along-with-column-n)

I tried doing below from hive terminal and it works.

```
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
```

However when I try saving the file to csv from command line it still puts the table name in column names.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Query used from CLI:-

```
bee_line --outputformat=csv2 --showHeader=true --silent=true -e "select * from salesdata.ales" >path-to-csv
```

where bee_line is an alias for full connection string stored in bash profile.

Comment: Could you please post the beeline command executed to store it to csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set hive properties as arguments to `beeline` using the `--hiveconf` option.

Your command would look like,

```
bee_line --hiveconf hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false -outputformat=csv2 --showHeader=true --silent=true -e "select * from salesdata.ales" >path-to-csv
```

**Note:** [Restricted properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Restricted/Hidden/InternalListandWhitelist) cannot be passed to this option.